# Rails Irregular Plural Association Name in Strong Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have a "LineOfBusiness" model which has an irregular pluralization ("lines_of_business" instead of "line_of_businesses").

I've set up my "has_many through" associations and made what I thought were the necessary adjustments for the irregular name, but I'm not sure why I'm having to use the plural form of the IDs in the strong params. The singular "user_ids" works in the params as I expected, but I have to use the plural "lines_of_business_ids" to get them to work properly. It seems like something small is off, but I can't figure it out.

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_questions
  has_many :line_of_business_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lines_of_business, through: :line_of_business_questions, :source => :line_of_business
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :user_questions
end

class LineOfBusiness < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "lines_of_business"
  has_many :line_of_business_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :line_of_business_questions
end

def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:name, :input_type, user_ids: [], lines_of_business_ids: [])
end
```

Comment: what is off about it? you've said a `question` has_many `lines_of_business` but if you want to make it singular, you can do so: try changing it to the following: `has_many :line_of_business, through: :line_of_business_questions, :source => :line_of_business` and see if that works, but to me, the old nomenclature makes the most sense.

Comment: That's correct, but I'm confused why I've also said a `question` has_many `users` yet that works with the singular `user_ids` in strong params. It's the discrepancy between the two that I don't understand.

Comment: I haven't had a look at the internals of the rails conventions to make this comment, but perhaps it's because you've aliased it to `lineS_of_business` (i.e. the plural lines) rather than, for example, having the plural on the very end e.g. `line_of_businessES`

Comment: This might be it. I'd since gone back and changed the plural form of the Model in the inflections.rb file instead of changing the table name directly as I was doing above. After that, `line_of_business_ids` worked fine in strong params.

Comment: if I write it up as an answer, can you accept it?

Comment: Sure. Maybe mention the table name vs inflection clue.